# How to check if one or more items are in an array and why this method isn't working?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to check if a string object is inside of an array using the include function. But, surprising, I got the correct check for the first element but not for the second, as shown in this Google Apps Script console:

[image]

Why is `(include(allThesesTypeArray, targetDocPart2))` returning `false`?

```
var speechList = [
                 ["With I/O Speech, Larry Page Reminds Us Why Google Rules Tech", "SCIENCE", "1_73vcRQ3gOySzSe2MXbW6zalRkLZ6IeN8L8FBbzrlZU"],
                 ["Steve Jobs: How to live before you die", "SCIENCE", "1ogS60eobk-gmO8fi14QYdIQmifCmEfAtrbIsGyMIr_Y"],
                 ["Salman Khan: Let's use video to reinvent education", "MATH", "1ggsGuhSbpMBEOS8a0GXTtwgbwvofKcOCxfX4B3SclTI"],
                ];

var targetDocPart1 = "SCIENCE";
var targetDocPart2 = "MATH";


 function include(arr, obj) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == obj) return true;
        else return false;
    }
 }


function teste(){
    var allThesesTypeArray = []; // To control Theses type apparence in the final doc
  for (var i = 0; i < speechList.length; i++) {
     var thesesType = speechList[i][1];
     if ( !(include(allThesesTypeArray, thesesType)) ){
        allThesesTypeArray.push(thesesType);     }
   }

  Logger.log("allThesesTypeArray = " + allThesesTypeArray);
  Logger.log("");
  Logger.log("targetDocPart1 = " + targetDocPart1);
  Logger.log(" (include(allThesesTypeArray, targetDocPart1)) = " + (include(allThesesTypeArray, targetDocPart1)));
  Logger.log("");
   Logger.log("targetDocPart2 = " + targetDocPart2);
  Logger.log(" (include(allThesesTypeArray, targetDocPart2)) = " + (include(allThesesTypeArray, targetDocPart2))); 
  Logger.log("");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is guaranteed to return on the first iteration. Certainly that's not what you want.

```
 function include(arr, obj) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == obj) // if we find a match, return true
            return true;
    }
    return false; // if we got here, there was no match, so return false
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning immediately, so if the element doesn't match you ll get `false` only. You can use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function like this

```
 function include(arr, obj) {
    return arr.some(function(currentItem) {
        return (currentItem === obj);
    }
 }
```

This will return `true` immediately, if any of the values match the input `obj`. Check this [`working demo`](http://ideone.com/anLUEb).

Answer (score 1):

You should clear your for -> if statement, moving the return false out of the for

```
function include(arr, obj) {
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == obj) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it will be better if you use native function

```
function include(arr, obj) {
    return arr.indexOf(obj) > 0 ? true : false;
}
```